# Why some Django view classes had not been defined as abstract base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, abstract-class

I'm writing a small and lightweight Django-like back-end framework for myself just for experiment.

If we look at `ProcessFormView` view(and some other views):

```py
class ProcessFormView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    ...
```

To me it sounds like a valid case to define this class as an "abstract base class".

After all, It needs that sub-classes provide `render_to_response()`, `get_context_data()`, `get_form()`, `form_valid()`, `form_invalid()`. (They will be provided by `TemplateResponseMixin` and `FormMixin`.)

I can do something like this:

```py
class ProcessFormView(View, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def render_to_response(self, context):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_context_data(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_form(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def form_valid(self, form):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        pass

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    ...
```

Or even better we can factor these abstract methods out to another ABC class and inherit from it to clear things up.

I know that of course it's a made decision and nothing is wrong with it. I mostly interested to know if do what I just showed, how can it cause problem in future? what would be the cons that I'm not aware of?

The only disadvantage that I can think about is I should then write many abstract classes! This make the code base much bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the mentioned fact that the code base would become much bigger, I think I found the main reason.

It's true that if we subclass `ProcessFormView` and "*intend to use its `get` and `post` method*", we have to eventually somehow provide those mentioned methods. But what if for some reason we only want to use its `post` method and provide our own custom method for `get`? (They are only get called inside `post` and `get`).

This way we no longer *have to* implement the `render_to_response` and `get_context_data()` abstract method. Defining them as `abstractmethod`s would unnecessarily force sub-classes to implement them.